# Rails : assets not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

> assets not working on Heroku (js/jQuery/image)

I am new to ruby and I have a little problem, I created a landing page that works perfectly on local (images are showing up, animation on js are also working).

But on Heroku, images are still here but animations are not working.

There is something weird, even if it's working when I check the console I have plenty of errors :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
font-awesome.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
application-18ac3fd2669832ec776c17e2e795d1fa260c46da2ba1ea9854a54227ada3a7cd.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakpoints' of undefined
    at application-18ac3fd2669832ec776c17e2e795d1fa260c46da2ba1ea9854a54227ada3a7cd.js:6
    at application-18ac3fd2669832ec776c17e2e795d1fa260c46da2ba1ea9854a54227ada3a7cd.js:6
jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pages.scss:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.scrollex.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
banner.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pic02.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pic01.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.scrolly.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
skel.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
util.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pic03.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
font-awesome.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
pages.scss:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have an index.html.erb page that call the scripts :

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

My scripts are in a folder `app/assets/javascripts/js`.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's not right to use it like this:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Check this out: [`The Asset Pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

You should put the all js files into `app/assets/javascripts` without `jquery.min.js`, because this library includes rails by default.

I believe the `javascripts/application.js` should be like this (by default):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//... example 
//= require_tree .
```

this `//= require_tree .` automatically maps the `javascripts` folder for all js files.

Remove this line `//= require rails-ujs` after edited like above.

And the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` should be like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

**Update**

You should place the `pages.scss` into `assets/stylesheets/` and create a file inside `assets/stylesheets/` like `custom.scss` then the `custom.scss` like this

```
@import "pages";
```

Comment: I dont understand why it is working on local whereas i have errors in my terminal for all my assets "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/css/pages.scss")"

Comment: Pretty good answer, +1 for the Assest Pipeline reference. However since Rails 5.1 jQuery is no longer a default dependency. https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/4/27/Rails-5-1-final/

Comment: @DedeBanell see the ***Update*** section

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include scripts in *index.html.erb*.

In your *app/views/layouts/application.erb*, there should be the following line exists.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => 'reload' %>
```

In your *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* you shouls see a line 
`//= require_tree .`

In your app/assets/javascripts create any .js file and write your code. It will work in all views without including anywhere.

If your animations are not working, try moving the following line from `<head>`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

to above closing body tag. i.e., `</body>`